# How do private photos get stolen?

Tags: privacy, data-leakage

I'm not referring to any of the below:

- A spiteful partner sharing private photos of the other after editing themselves out.
- Someone stealing photos from a professional photographer/artist without permission.
- Enthusiasts leaking their own private photos/videos to make news.

I guess they're stolen from an insecure system which is connected to the internet/intranet.  How do they get stolen from mobile-phones and handy-cams?  Are the service centers playing any role during routine services?

How can I be extra careful to avoid such a mess?

Just curious...

Answer (score 3):

Often times compromised passwords are the most direct route.  If someone's e-mail account or online storage get compromised, then anything in them is up for grabs.  This is the purported way that many leaks occur.  There are lots of others ways that it could happen, but those are probably the most common after "intentionally leaked for publicity".

Answer (score 2):

These days social networking sites like facebook provide the most rich and easy access to your private data. Most pictures that goes there comes from use of mobile fones or handy cams.

legally to classify anything as "stealing" the victim in most cases have to give reasonable proof of the measures and precaution he or she has used to protect its private info.

So a user who has its facebook privacy settings into public mode can't held anyone responsible for sharing his pictures.

Also, sometimes logging to insecure terminals like in netcafe you expose yourself to threats of remote keyloggers to capture your email passwords email accounts are just another great source of user private data.